# Issue using a var in a global

Tags: jquery, global, var

I try to have the content of an element in an editable box and I have trouble rendering a var in a global.

```
var editid  = $(this).closest("div").attr("id"); // works
```

Lets say the id is special1

Lets say content of special1 is "real content of special1"

If I use:

```
var valuee1 = '%%GLOBAL_' + editid + '%%';
```

valuee1 will return textualy : %%GLOBAL_special1%%

If I use:

```
var valuee2 = '%%GLOBAL_special1%%';
```

valuee2  will return = 'real content of special1';

The issue is I need to use a var (valuee1) since this function is designed to work onclick on elements with different ids, so I do not know how to do make it work. The rest of the code works fine.

```
var $cbox = $('<input />').attr({
    type: 'textarea',
    name: editid,
    value: valuee1,
    "class": 'click'
}); 
$p.after($cbox); // this creates a box with content
```

Comment: This is a really badly formed question. I have no idea what you're even asking or what the problem is.. Ask a question, use a question mark.

Comment: You're asking how to access a variable whose name is in another variable?

Comment: If the `valuee2` assignment works, I think it means you're using a template framework that expands `%%` patterns. But it only expands them when they're in the Javascript source code, not when the pattern is created dynamically.

Comment: I am asking how to make this code return the content of the element :var valuee1 = '%%GLOBAL_' + editid + '%%';

Comment: Yes I understand (your second comment), is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById()` to find the DOM element with the ID, and then get its content.

```
var valuee1 = document.getElementById(editid).textContent;
```

Comment: That won't work for my setup, I need to get the content from the Data bank, not from the html (it is different because some content is added dynamiclay onload).

Comment: Then replace `document.getElementById()` with whatever function returns content from the Data bank. I have no idea what that is, there's nothing about it in the question.

Comment: I think I got the point. I know how to query the dbase, so I will do it the other way. You explained why it did not work, clear enough for me, thank you.